# Bind event to all socket.io connections

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I know it's possible to emit events to all connections using `io.sockets.emit('some event')`, but can I also globally bind events to all present and future connections? Would probably look like

```
io.sockets.on('feedTheDog', function (data) {
    // Someone told me to feed the dog..
});
```

Also, can I remove event listeners with [`.removeAllListeners()`](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_removealllisteners_event) with Socket.IO?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that. At least I do not know it. But do you really need it? You may just emit `common` event with `status` field in `data` and check if `(data.status == 'feedTheDog')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also don't think you can bind events to future connections, but yes, you can use removeAllListeners with socket.io. They ported node's event emitter to the browser, so it's exactly the same api there. Here's the code for it: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client/blob/master/lib/events.js

Answer (score 0):

You can use `socket.io-events` and attach `middleware` functions to handle messages for all socket connections, without actually attaching a handler to a socket.